# How to remove omgubuntu web app from ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, webapps

I tried using methods found in different posts on this forum, but they do not work because my system tells me that that app is not installed.

Any help ?

EDIT: **** Just now i installed Ubuntu Vibes web app, and it points to a wrong page when clicked and now I can't remove it xD

Comment: What things have to tried?  Can you give some links so we know where you're at?

Comment: I tried searching for the app in software center. I tried using unsettings to disable the app. I tried dragging the icon to the trash can :) All with no luck. I tried typing random stuff in cmd to remove it ...

Comment: Please post back your orginal method of installation

Comment: I went to www.omgubuntu.co.uk/some_page, then it asked me to allow something. I said yes, and voila i had omgubuntu installed on my pc. When i click on the icon i goes to a specific site on omgubuntu. I checked firefox add-ons, and omgubuntu is not there either. EDIT: Now when i click on the icon it does nothing. I think unsettings is guilty of that.

Comment: Okey ... now i used sqlite database browser to open databases found in ~/.local/share/unity-webapps/ and deleted entries for omgubuntu and ubuntu vibes and in folder resources deleted their icons. But they are still shown in dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used *sqlite database browser* to open databases found in `~/.local/share/unity-webapps/` and deleted entries for omgubuntu and ubuntu vibes and in folder resources deleted their icons. Then I went to `~/.local/share/applications/` and deleted related *.desktop files.
But they are still shown in dash so i restarted my PC and they are gone.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch `dconf-editor` (You may need to install it from the Ubuntu
   Software Center).
2. Go to `com` » `canonical` » `unity` » `webapps`.
3. Edit the key `allowed-domains` and remove the occurrence `omgubuntu.co.uk` from the list.
4. Remove any files containing `omgubuntu.co.uk` from `~/.local/share/applications/`. From a terminal (you should be asked for confirmation):

   rm ~/.local/share/applications/*omgubuntu*.desktop
5. For total cleanup, remove the icons from `~/.local/share/icons/unity-webapps/`. From a terminal, again:

   find ~/.local/share/icons/unity-webapps/ -iname *omgubuntu*.png -exec rm {} ';'